# ClearCase UCM: Change Project Type?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am working with ClearCase UCM.  We have a project that has been created as a **'single stream' Project Type.**

We now wish this to have **multiple child streams**.

**Is there a way to change this after creation?**  If so, how?  Or does this need to be recreated?

I have looked into commands that change the project, but other than policies, I can't see if something may be related - and I can't see any related policy names - but this is fairly new to me, I just happen to have the most experience in my area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple/multi-stream nature of an UCM project is determined at its creation with [`cleartool mkproj -model`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkproject.htm?cp=SSSH27_9.0.0&lang=en).
The "model" (simple or default) is not something you can change by policy or with [`cleartool chproj`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_chproject.htm).

That is why the IBM help page on "[Single-stream projects](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_u_pln_prj_sstrm.htm)" says:

> You may want to use a single-stream project during the initial stage of development when several developers want to share code quickly.
>
> **When the development effort expands and you need a parallel development environment, you can create a multiple-stream project based on the final baselines in the single-stream project**.

Comment: Straight to the point, and obviously something I missed in my searches.  Thanks again (even though this is my first post, practically everything else I've learnt about CC is from your answers!).

Comment: @Ads Glad to help. For your first question, it was a good one.